# Google Cloud Run - Request delays

Tags: delay, google-cloud-run

We are currently testing out Google Cloud Run for a node.js docker-service. So far it seems pretty neat, but when the service has been idling for some time, it seems that the first request is pretty slow ( ~3sec to serve a static page, following reqs completes in ~0.2sec ). Since our application is quite sensitive to delays, we would like to avoid such delays.

We tried to enable the "CPU always allocated" preview functionality, but it doesn't seem to solve our problem.

Does anyone know if there's something to do here, or if we should look for another service?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :)
Source # Google Documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times

Idle instances
As traffic fluctuates, Cloud Run attempts to reduce the chance of cold starts by keeping some idle instances around to handle spikes in traffic. For example, when a container instance has finished handling requests, it might remain idle for a period of time in case another request needs to be handled.

Cloud Run
But, Cloud Run will terminate unused containers after some time if no requests need to be handled. This means a cold start can still occur. Container instances are scaled as needed, and it will initialize the execution environment completely. While you can keep idle instances permanently available using the min-instance setting, this incurs cost even when the service is not actively serving requests.

So, let’s say you want to minimize both cost and response time latency during a possible cold start. You don’t want to set a minimum number of idle instances, but you also know any additional computation needed upon container startup before it can start listening to requests means longer load times and latency.

Cloud Run container startup
There are a few tricks you can do to optimize your service for container startup times. The goal here is to minimize the latency that delays a container instance from serving requests. But first, let’s review the Cloud Run container startup routine.

When Starting the service

- Starting the container
- Running the entrypoint command to start your
  server
- Checking for the open service port

You want to tune your service in order to minimize the time needed for step 1a. Let’s walk through 3 ways to optimize your service for Cloud Run response times.

1. Create a leaner service
2. Use a leaner base image
3. Use global variables

Comment: Thanks a lot! Carefully reading the docs seems to be a pretty clever strategy ;-) We managed to fix the issue by setting min instances to 0.

Comment: Please mark answer useful if it will help you  :)